# Android: How to receive process signals in an activity to kill child process?

Tags: android, exec, kill, signals

My application calls Runtime.exec() to launch an executable in a
separate process at start up time. I would like this child process to
get killed when the parent activity exits. Now I can use onDestroy()
to handle regular cases, but not "Force quit", shutdowns from DDMS, or
kill from the console since those don't run onDestroy().
The addShutdownHandler() does not seem to be invoked in these cases
either.

Is there any other hook or signal handler that informs my activity
that it's about to get terminated ? As an alternative is there a way
to have the system automatically kill the child process when the
parent dies ?

Comment: It would be easier to suggest a solution if you tell us a little more about why you're creating a separate process with Runtime.exec() in the first place.  If the child process were closely coupled (e.g. open socket for communication) then the child would naturally die when the parent went away.  I gather that isn't the case?

Comment: There is no tight coupling between the two. The spawned process is basically a web server, with the activity serving as a configuration / control panel. Button presses in the activity simply map to POST calls to the spawned server. However, the server should not be running when the UI has been forcefully terminated.

Comment: There might be a more system-friendly way to create the web server (e.g. make it a service); hopefully somebody more familiar can explain how that would work.  One solution might be to create a thread in the web server that does a blocking read on stdin.  If that returns EOF, it means the parent has died, and the child can kill itself.  (Haven't tried it myself.)

Comment: Excellent suggestion! My child process now does a blocking read which gets interrupted when the spawning parent activity dies. 

Do you want to turn this comment into a "proper" stackoverflow answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main() {
  // Spawn a new thread here to do your work
  start_thread();

  char dummy[10]; 
  gets(dummy);
  // When parent dies we reach this line, before that process is blocked in gets line above
  return 0;
}
```